# pyaudio не ставится

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyaudio

Пытаюсь установить `PyAudio`

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Не работает:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\vmn3w\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ty3x32jf\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\vmn3w\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ty3x32jf\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\vmn3w\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-a8af960l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Пытаюсь с помощью `pipwin`:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Тоже не работает:

```
Package `pyaudio` found in cache
Downloading package . . .
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/z4tqcw5k/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vmn3w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pipwin-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pipwin==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pipwin')()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 103, in main
    cache.install(package)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 300, in install
    wheel_file = self.download(requirement)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 294, in download
    return self._download(requirement, dest)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 290, in _download
    obj.start()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pySmartDL\pySmartDL.py", line 267, in start
    urlObj = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=self.timeout, context=self.context)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Уже и питон переустанавливал, все равно не получается. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй скачать бинарник и его установить через pip
[ссылка на бинарники](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/586589)

Comment: Поправил, спасибо за информацию!